# How do I check if a outer type is a type of inner type?

Tags: go

If I have different forms of user structs being passed around my application is there a way to check if that embedded struct is a type of the outer struct?

```
type (
    user struct {
        name  string
        email string
    }
    admin struct {
        user
        level string
    }
)
```

Comment: Use http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/ to if it's the original user struct or the inherited one.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on you need, you have two main methods: [`reflect.TypeOf`](https://godoc.org/reflect#TypeOf), and the [type swtich](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch).

You will use the first to compare the type of an interface with another one. Example:

```
if reflect.TypeOf(a) == reflect.TypeOf(b) {
    doSomething()
}
```

You will use the second to do a particular action given the type of an interface. Example:

```
switch a.(type) {
    case User:
        doSomething()
    case Admin:
        doSomeOtherThing()
}
```